# Xcode 11.2.1 not showing object in library

Tags: xcode, swiftui, macos-catalina

I do not have objects in my Xcode Library.
Xcode  - Version 11.2.1 (11B500)
OS Catalina  -  10.15.1 (19B88)
[image]
It was about hour ago and then disappeared. Xcode restarted, Macbook restarted. Last stable Xcode and Catalina OS.

Comment: can you please update the screenshot with the fullsize one, including the Xcode window itself?

Comment: Solved. It was my fault. To see Objects in Library you need to see Canvas in your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Library automatically changes according to what file you are editing (plus some configurations for the file like Canvas open state). For example:

**ViewController.swift**
[image]

**Main.Storyboard**
[image]

**MyProject**
[image]

As you can see, each file represents a different library with different taps and different default tap is selected. So make sure a design (`.storyboard` or `.xib`) file is selected and try again.

**Note that** sometimes you need to open **Canvas** to see *Objects* in *Library* if you are using **SwiftUI**

<sub>**Also note that** you should check the other monitor too if you have multiple monitors.</sub>

Comment: I edit same file, it show me hours ago library with objects tab(it was 5 tabs) - now I have only 3 as in my picture

Comment: I have added a note about canvas to make it more clear.